# Generar pdf en lote dompdf

Tags: php, pdf

Necesito generar varios pdf a partir de una subida de archivo csv y descargarlos automáticamente, lo intente con un ciclo while, pero nada, no descarga

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código. Saludos.

Comment: Recuerda que solo puedes descargar un archivo a la vez. Si quieres descargarlos todos, genera un comprimido (zip).